# How to call a function within a function from another function?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views

I'm trying to implement Test numbering scheme. On the screen to display/modify a numbering scheme there is a button to test that scheme. The goal of that button is, that the numbering scheme can be tested using the def testnums, which should call the def nextNums. The result should be displayed in a way you can define, but as such, that the user can easily see if the increment produced the desired result.

```
@login_required
def nextNums (request, inAppName):
    try:
        numsEntry             = get_object_or_404(RDdbNums, application=request.inAppName)
    except:
        numsEntry             = RDdbPref()
        numsEntry.application = inAppName
        numsEntry.nextnbr     = inAppName + "-000001"
        numsEntry.scheme      = inAppName + "-nnnnnn"
        numsEntry.ncount      = 6
        numsEntry.reccount    = 1
        numsEntry.recincr     = 1
        numsEntry.Comment     = "default value created by rddb"
        numsEntry.createdBy   = request.user
        numsEntry.modifiedBy  = request.user

    nextNumNbr = numsEntry.nextnbr

    writeLogfileEntry(request, 0, 'nextNums.nextnbr ' + inAppName + ' ' + nextNumNbr)

    numsEntry.nextnbr = numsEntry.scheme

    writeLogfileEntry(request, 0, 'numsEntry.scheme ' + inAppName + ' ' + numsEntry.nextnbr)

    numsEntry.nextnbr = (numsEntry.nextnbr.replace("YYYY", datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y')))
    numsEntry.nextnbr = (numsEntry.nextnbr.replace("yy",   datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%y')))
    numsEntry.nextnbr = (numsEntry.nextnbr.replace("MM",   datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m')))
    numsEntry.nextnbr = (numsEntry.nextnbr.replace("DD",   datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%d')))

    nextNumTxt = str(numsEntry.reccount)
    while len(nextNumTxt) < numsEntry.ncount:
        nextNumTxt = '0' + nextNumTxt

    if   numsEntry.ncount == 9:
        numsEntry.nextnbr = (numsEntry.nextnbr.replace("nnnnnnnnn", nextNumTxt))
    elif numsEntry.ncount == 8:
        numsEntry.nextnbr = (numsEntry.nextnbr.replace("nnnnnnnn",  nextNumTxt))
    elif numsEntry.ncount == 7:
        numsEntry.nextnbr = (numsEntry.nextnbr.replace("nnnnnnn",   nextNumTxt))
    elif numsEntry.ncount == 6:
        numsEntry.nextnbr = (numsEntry.nextnbr.replace("nnnnnn",    nextNumTxt))
    elif numsEntry.ncount == 5:
        numsEntry.nextnbr = (numsEntry.nextnbr.replace("nnnnn",     nextNumTxt))
    elif numsEntry.ncount == 4:
        numsEntry.nextnbr = (numsEntry.nextnbr.replace("nnnn",      nextNumTxt))
    elif numsEntry.ncount == 3:
        numsEntry.nextnbr = (numsEntry.nextnbr.replace("nnn",       nextNumTxt))
    elif numsEntry.ncount == 2:
        numsEntry.nextnbr = (numsEntry.nextnbr.replace("nn",        nextNumTxt))
    elif numsEntry.ncount == 1:
        numsEntry.nextnbr = (numsEntry.nextnbr.replace("n",         nextNumTxt))

    writeLogfileEntry(request, 0, 'nextEntry.nextnbr ' + inAppName + ' ' + numsEntry.nextnbr)

    numsEntry.reccount = numsEntry.reccount + numsEntry.recincr

    numsEntry.save()
    return nextNumNbr
```

Test numbering scheme:
[image: my image]

```
@login_required
def testnums(request):
    writeLogfileEntry(request, 0, 'testnums entering function')
    
    return render(request, 'mainpage/testnums.html', {'dispCount':dispCount})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on scopes in python,you can't call an inner-defined function from another function.What you can do is that you return the inner function and use it somewhere else.
like this:

```
def main_func():
  def inner_func:
    # do stuff
  return inner_func
var = main_func()
var() # now you can call var()
```